# Creating a Object with same Structure than received json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hola Developers im trying to create a product in my shopping card , but still im stacked in one issue :
Can't find the proper way to design a object just on the same way i receive it from my json (back-end).
Lets say the part is causing the issue is this:

```
JSON RECEIVED

"product_category": [
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Good"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Danger"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Homer"
        }
      ],
      "people_buying_this_product": "Jack Ripper"
    },
]
```

then on my building-product-processs , on the data  return  is a section that  have to do with this, where in then using checkboxes i get which checkbox is checked or not , in order to build a array of categories similar to the former one i have shown:

```
DATA RETURN


      ProductAdded: {
        description: "",
        upload_image3: "",
        upload_image2: "",
        upload_image1: "",
        unities: 0,
        price: 0,
        name: "",
        Categories: [
          { id: 1, value: "Miscellaneous", selected: false },
          { id: 2, value: "Homer", selected: false },
          { id: 3, value: "Electronic", selected: false },
          { id: 4, value: "Internet", selected: true },
          { id: 5, value: "Kids", selected: false },
          { id: 6, value: "Donas", selected: true },
          { id: 7, value: "Sports", selected: true },
          { id: 8, value: "Horror", selected: false }
        ],

METHOD that dispatches de action in vuex

addProductOnSale(thisCurrent) {
      this.$store.dispatch("addProductSale", this.ProductAdded);
    }
```

then being already in the VUEX state management , on the action in fact , trying to build the new product for this product category, i set this:

```
 addProductSale({commit,getters},currentProduct){
    product_category: currentProduct.Categories.filter(option => 
    option.selected).map(option => {categories_of_product: option.value})
}
```

------------------->this one  gives me undefined like:

```
"product_category": 

        [
          undefined
        ],
"product_category": 

        [
          undefined
        ],
   "product_category": 

        [
          undefined
        ],

]
```

or tried this other :

```
 addProductSale({commit,getters},currentProduct){
    product_category:currentProduct.Categories.forEach( option.selected,() => 
    option.value).map(option => option.selected),...
}
```

and gave me error , not even showing a result.
Basically cant find the way to design the same structure im receiving for json , nor even reaching to values.
Is weird ,but if i only set the query like this:

```
 addProductSale({commit,getters},currentProduct){
    product_category:currentProduct.Categories.filter(option => option.selected)
}
```

Indeed filters and gives back the objects inside Categories which commit the condition of selected true , but with its plain format just as the data returns , but that's not the idea.
Any advice or help?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: to create an Object from JSON, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: `currentProduct.Categories` should be `currentProduct.ProductAdded.Categories`

Comment: `{ undefined }` is not possible, everything inside `{}` is in the form of `key: value`

Comment: Barma , i ommited part of code but basically this is buld in vuex , ProductAdded was set as parameter in a dispatch method in the component